# Select All CSV then Paste All to Google Sheet - Time Out Issue

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, this code does exactly what I need it to do with one issue, if there is too much data for it to move, Google times out and will end the process. In full honestly/transparency, I'm a total script-code noob, so I might be missing something really simple. From what I can tell, this codes stacks data row by row, and if there are too many rows, this is where my breakdown comes in.  Is there a why to just select all data, and paste all data?  Thanks for your help!

```
function importDataCDOP() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('FILE PATH'); 
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('xxxx.csv'); 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('FILE PATH');     
  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { 

    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var first = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');

    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); 
    var newsheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA'); 

    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');
    var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
    destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      destSheet.getRange(lastRow + i + 1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }


     file.setName("OP report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
  }
};

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );

  var arrData = [[]];
  var arrMatches = null;
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }
  return( arrData );
};
```

Comment: Can I ask you about what you want to do? In your script, you want to import the csv data from a file with the filename of "xxxx.csv" to the spreadsheet with the file ID of "FILE PATH". Here, when "xxxx.csv" has the large csv data, the elapsed time of your script is over the time limitation. You want to modify your script for this issue. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for replying.  You are correct.  I need to find a way to "copy and paste" the data over faster.  The above script takes too long with the looping and Google will stop the script.  I can manually copy and paste in 20K+ lines of data faster than this code can load 1000 lines of data.  But I need to load data daily, hence why a script is preferred. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I posted my answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and comment, I could understand that you want to import the csv data from a file of "xxxx.csv" to the sheet of "NEWDATA" on the spreadsheet of "FILE PATH", and when the large csv data is imported, the elapsed time is over the time limitation of Google Apps Script. I understood that this was your issue. For this situation, how about this modification? Although I'm not sure whether this modification can directly solve your issue, please try to run this.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve a file object using `getFilesByName('xxxx.csv').next()`, because the csv file is only one.
- `var first = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');` and `var newsheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');` are not used in your script.

  - Removed them.
- In your script, the 2 dimensional array of csv data is imported by every element.

  - I thought that this may be the main cause of your issue.
  - In the modified script, import the 2 dimensional array at once.

#### Modified script :

I modified only `importDataCDOP()`.

```
function importDataCDOP() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('FILE PATH');
  var file = fSource.getFilesByName('xxxx.csv').next();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('FILE PATH');
  var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csv).filter(String);
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NEWDATA');
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  file.setName("OP report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
};
```

#### Note :

- I didn't modify `CSVToArray()`.
- `filter(String)` remove the elements with only the line break.
- If this modified script was over the limitation of execution time, I would like to propose to use Sheets API.

If I misunderstand your question and the elapsed time of modified script was over the limitation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you again for your quick reply... I will test this out, and get back to you!